# log4j - Provider jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngineFactory not found

Tags: java, logging, log4j

So I just wanted to add log4j to a project.
Downloaded the archive from the website and copied the two .jar files,

```
log4j-api-2.6.2.jar
log4j-core-2.6.2.jar
```

into my lib folder as per instruction at the bottom of http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/download.html

Following the example on http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/api.html , I commented out most of my main function and just tested it like this:

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;

public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {(new Main(args)).run();}

    private static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(Main.class);

    public Main(String[] args){
        //log.error because I did not yet bother with the log4j.properties file
        log.error("Started Main");
    }

    public void run(){
        System.out.println("RUNNING!");
    }

}
```

What I do get is:

```
 [java] ScriptEngineManager providers.next(): javax.script.ScriptEngineFactory: Provider jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngineFactory not found
 [java] 15:12:07.918 [main] ERROR Main - Started Main
 [java] RUNNING!
```

java version: 1.8.0_77, if that matters.

I do have an (as of yet empty) `log4j.properties` file in my classpath, but that's not relevant as without it, I'm simply getting

```
 [java] ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration: logging only errors to the console.
 [java] ScriptEngineManager providers.next(): javax.script.ScriptEngineFactory: Provider jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngineFactory not found
 [java] 15:15:27.545 [main] ERROR Main - Started Main
 [java] RUNNING!
```

How do I resolve this?

And need I resolve this at all or will log4j function anyway? We can see the error, at least, still seems to work. Didn't get to test the other levels yet because I need to first [figure out how to and then] set up that properties file.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70962017/problem-with-javax-script-scriptenginefactory-after-migration-log4j2 same problem